# Highstock, Zoom with Buttons for 3 different yAxis

Tags: javascript, button, highcharts, zooming

I have some problem with my project.
I want to add a button (3 buttons) to my highstock chart for zooming my YAxis. When clicked values should be read out of a text field and min/max of the yAxis should be set. I found the function setExtremes(min,max) in the documentation, but i can’t get it work. A picture of my Chart is linked below, my code too. I'm thankful for any help and solutions.
Yours sincerely 
Patrick

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> CA01</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Highstock-2.1.8/exporting-server/phantomjs/jquery.1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(function () {
        var filename = window.location.pathname;
        var mysplit = filename.split('/', 6);
        filename = mysplit[4];
        var seriesOptions = [],
            seriesCounter = 0,

            names = ['CA01F01X_OPC', 'CA01F01XSUM_OPC', 'CA01F02X_OPC', 'CA01F02XSUM_OPC', 'CA01F03X_OPC', 'CA01F03XSUM_OPC', 'CA01P01X_OPC', 'CA01P01ASP_OPC', 'CA01P02X_OPC','CA01P02ASP_OPC','CA01T01X_OPC','CA01T01ASP_OPC'],

       createChart = function () {

                $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
                    //Titel
                    title: {
                        text: filename,
                        x: -20 //center
                    },
                    //Untertitel
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'CA01',
                        x: -20
                    },

                    rangeSelector: {
                        buttons: [{
                            type: 'minute',
                            count:30,
                            text: '30min'
                        },{
                            type: 'hour',
                            count: 1,
                            text: '1h'
                        },{
                            type: 'hour',
                            count: 12,
                            text: '12h'
                        }, {
                            type: 'day',
                            count: 1,
                            text: '1d'
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'all',
                            text: 'all'
                        }],
                        selected: 0
                    },
                    dataGrouping: {
                        approximation: 'high'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        gridLineWidth: 1
                    },
                    //y-Achsen
                    yAxis: [

                        {
                        labels: {
                            format: '{value}',
                            style: {
                                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                            }
                        },

                        title:{ 
                            text: 'Temperatur [°C]',
                            style: {
                                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                            }
                        },
                        height: '30%',
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        offset: 0,
                        //Seite der Achse
                        opposite: false,
                        //Minimum, max: für Maximum
                        min: 0,
                        minPadding: 0.02,
                        maxPadding: 0.02,
                        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 2,
                            color: 'silver'
                        }
                        ]
                        },
                        //2.Achse
                        {
                        labels: {
                            format: '{value}',
                            style: {
                                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                            }
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Druck [bar]',
                            style: {
                                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                            }
                        },
                        //Höhe der Achse
                        height: '30%',
                        //Abstand der Achse vom oberen Bildrand (damit zwei achsen nicht übereinander liegen)
                        top: '34%',
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        offset: 0,
                        opposite: false,
                        min: 0,
                        minPadding: 0.02,
                        maxPadding: 0.02,
                        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 2,
                            color: 'silver'
                        }]
                    },
                    //3.Achse
                    {
                        labels: {
                            format: '{value}',
                            style: {
                                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                            }
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Durchfluss [Nl/h]',
                            style: {
                                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                            }
                        },
                        height: '15%',
                        top: '67%',
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        offset: 0,
                        opposite: false,
                        min: 0,
                        minPadding: 0.02,
                        maxPadding: 0.02,
                        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 2,
                            color: 'silver'
                        }]
                    },
                    //4. Achse
                    {
                        labels: {
                            format: '{value}',
                            style: {
                                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                            }
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Volumen [Nl]',
                            style: {
                                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                            }
                        },
                        height: '15%',
                        top: '85%',
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        offset: 0,
                        opposite: false,
                        min: 0,
                        minPadding: 0.02,
                        maxPadding: 0.02,
                        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 2,
                            color: 'silver'
                        }]
                    }
                    ],

                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {

                        }
                    },

                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
                        valueDecimals: 2
                    },

                    legend: {
                        enabled: true,
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'center',
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        borderWidth: 1
                    },

                    series: seriesOptions
                });
            };

        $.each(names, function (i, name) {
            //load Data
            $.getJSON(name+'.json', function (data) {
                if(name.contains('T01X')){
                    name = 'T01X'
                } else if (name.contains('T01ASP')){
                    name='T01ASP'
                } else if (name.contains('P01X')){
                    name='P01X'
                } else if (name.contains('P01ASP')){
                    name='P01ASP'
                } else if (name.contains('P02X')) {
                    name = 'P02X'
                } else if (name.contains('P02ASP')) {
                    name = 'P02ASP'
                } else if (name.contains('F01XSUM')) {
                    name = 'F01XSUM'
                } else if (name.contains('F01X')) {
                    name = 'F01X'
                } else if (name.contains('F02XSUM')) {
                    name = 'F02XSUM'
                } else if (name.contains('F02X')) {
                    name = 'F02X'
                } else if (name.contains('F03XSUM')) {
                    name = 'F03XSUM'
                } else if (name.contains('F03X')) {
                    name = 'F03X'
                }

                //choose y-Axis
                if (name === 'T01X'||name==='T01ASP') {
                    seriesOptions[i] = {
                        name: name,
                        data: data,
                        yAxis: 0
                    };
                } else if (name === 'P01X' || name === 'P01ASP' || name === 'P02X' || name === 'P02ASP') {
                    seriesOptions[i] = {
                        name: name,
                        data: data,
                        yAxis: 1
                    };
                } else if (name === 'F01X'|| name==='F02X'||name==='F03X') {
                    seriesOptions[i] = {
                        name: name,
                        data: data,
                        yAxis: 2
                    };
                }  else {
                    seriesOptions[i] = {
                        name: name,
                        data: data,
                        yAxis: 3
                    };
                };


                seriesCounter += 1;

                if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
                    createChart();
                }
            });
        });

    });


</script>
<script src="../../Highstock-2.1.8/js/highstock.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container" style="height: 1050px; min-width: 310px"></div>      
<div id = "test">
    Kommentar
    <input type="text" name="spind" value="" size="310" />
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfmyr.jpg)

Comment: Can you recreate the same in a jsFiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PatrickVCP/qt0xm0x4/3/

Comment: i had problems with my json-files - so i made an easier version, based on a highstock example. I now want zoom-buttons for the 2 yAxis, to set min/max by reading these out of a text field.

Comment: Update: I now integrated a button, the click action does work (text is written in a text box for testing). But i can't adress the yAxis or the chart to set the extremes... http://jsfiddle.net/PatrickVCP/qt0xm0x4/16/

Comment: The min/max values should be numbers. Reference to Highcharts is incorrect, should be $('#container').highcharts(). In case when you need to control yAxis, (I guess from input), you should use parseFloat(val) where val is input value. Fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/evf6vrpb/1/

Comment: Thank you very much, with a little bit of testing (thanks to js fiddle - i didn't know how to use this before) I found another solution: https://jsfiddle.net/PatrickVCP/qt0xm0x4/82/ witch works also